# Multiple versions of a same Weblogic Shared Library active on a same server

Tags: java, ejb, shared-libraries, weblogic11g

I am having an issue while trying to deploy two different versions of a same shared Library on the same weblogic server.

**Here is my goal:**

- I have multiple applications which reference a shared Library;
- those applications should be able to use different implementation version of this shared Library (in a very good world);
- So I would like to deploy multiple version of this shared Library (e.g.: AppB use the version 1.0.0 and AppA use the 1.0.1).

I think (know?) that is possible (I've seen on a weblogic exam that multiple version of a same shared lib can be deploy and active in the same time) but untill now I failed...

Weblogic is unhappy with the fact that two sharedlibrary have the same name... But this 'same name' is required by my applications to use those shared libraries...

**My META-INF files are :**

```
Extension-Name: app-local-services-ejb
Implementation-Version: 2.0.2-SNAPSHOT
Specification-Version: 2.0
```

and

```
Extension-Name: app-local-services-ejb
Implementation-Version: 2.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Specification-Version: 2.0
```

My weblogic-application files for the applications I only use the Extension Name of the web-inf and the specification version...

I've tried to do the same with two different version of JSF but I've got the same issue. 
The Oracle's documentation on shared Library is not really clear and I didn't find something useful on goole/bing.

I don't know if I have to upload those shared libraries in a specific folder (e.g.: weblogic/commom/deployable-libraries) or if I have to specify something in WEB-INF/weblogic-application.xml files ?

Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Can you separate the applications into two .ear/.war files, each with their own version of the library they need to use? This seems to be by far the easiest way around this problem.

Comment: Indeed this will work. Do you know why this happens? Why weblogic behaves with this way? In my case I get a classNotFoundException when I reference 2nd time the same shared lib jar.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one version of a library with the same spec version in a WLS at the same time.

To put a new implementation-version up, you'd have to *update* the existing deployment with the new jar, rather than deploying a new version. This will remove the lower-numbered implementation-version, if WLS can work it out.

This is why it's a very good idea to have spec-versions and implementation-versions be floats, since WLS has a much easier time working out which version is higher than the other if it can be cast to a float.

If, however, you have a library with a different spec number, you can happily upload it simultaneously with other spec numbers. Again, if WLS can work out the version numbers, it can transition apps to the new version automatically, provided they don't have exact-version set in their weblogic-application.xml.